# How can I get the outline of a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, cgpath

Is it possible to get the outline of an `UIView` as a `CGPath`? I've taken a look over the `UIView` and `CALayer` methods but I couldn't find anything useful.

**Edit**

Consider the image below. I want the `CGPath` that follows the border (assuming that outside the border the view is transparent). This is just an example, I need something that would work with any shapes.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to get the frame of an `UIView` as a `CGPath`?

Comment: No, the outline of the part of the view that has a color(transparent spaces should not be outlined).

Comment: Can you show image of what you want?

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

A UIView (or NSView in Mac) is a rectangular area by definition.  What you see in your Show Notification example is the result of drawing into that view.

Comment: I know that, but this does not answer the question.